# SharePoint InfoPath form postback issue

Tags: sharepoint, infopath

As a SharePoint developer I am reviewing a browser-enabled InfoPath 2010 form published to a SharePoint Online (Office 365) environment.
The InfoPath form contains several controls – textboxes, rich textboxes, dropdown listboxes, multiple-selection listboxes, date pickers and person/group pickers – and is published to a SharePoint Form Library. The users are facing the issue that whenever one control has been changed and loses focus, the form is getting a postback. Some of the postbacks are as expected, because another field will be updated because of a rule (conditional validation, formatting or action). But other postbacks I cannot explain. Trying to set the control’s property Browser forms > Postback settings to “Never” will not solve the issue.
Additional information : the dropdown listboxes and the multiple-selection listboxes receive their data by using a data connection that is bound to a SharePoint list adapter. On several dropdown listboxes and multiple-selection listboxes a filter is set.
Maybe you can give me a clue ?

Answer (score 0):

Try reading this [blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/infopath/archive/2008/06/19/designing-browser-enabled-forms-for-performance-in-infopath-forms-services-part-2.aspx).  It provides some good insights into what causes postbacks in InfoPath forms.

Comment: Dont use one-line answers including a link to a blog posting. The answer posted here must include the answer, not a link to a link to .... a link to the answer.